# Add active class to button in React Accessible Accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react. Can anyone please tell how can I add an 'active' class to accordion item or button when i click. I am Using React Accessible Accordion.

Codes are here, but not working

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import Podcast from '../Podcast';
import PodcastStats from '../PodcastStats';
import Data from '../../assets/data/data.json'

import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionItemHeading,
  AccordionItemButton,
  AccordionItemPanel
} from "react-accessible-accordion";

import '../../assets/styles/accordion.scss';

export default function CustomAccordion({ isActive }) {
  return (
    <Accordion allowZeroExpanded>
          <AccordionItem className={classNames({ "active": isActive })}>
            <AccordionItemHeading>
                <AccordionItemButton>
                    deneme
                </AccordionItemButton>
            </AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemPanel>
              <Podcast data={Data} />
            </AccordionItemPanel>
          </AccordionItem>
          <AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItemHeading>
                <AccordionItemButton>
                    deneme
                </AccordionItemButton>
            </AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemPanel>
              <PodcastStats data={Data} />
            </AccordionItemPanel>
          </AccordionItem>
    </Accordion>
  );
}
```

Comment: It should work if you have installed classNames and the `isActive` prop changes to true. Could you provide more code?

Comment: @JavierMolinasVilas I updated, can you look at this

Comment: I don't see something wrong in your code, could you see if `isActive` is changing to true?